# IBM MQ 9.1.0.0 AMQ9557E: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed for 'root'

Tags: configuration-managment

Having this:

```
07/16/19 15:39:23 - Process(16848.13) User(mqm) Program(amqzlaa0)
                Host(a95090b6b6b6) Installation(Installation1)
                VRMF(9.1.0.0) QMgr(MQ)
                Time(2019-07-16T15:39:23.672Z)
                CommentInsert1(root)
                CommentInsert2(QM)
                CommentInsert3(connect)
AMQ8077W: Entity 'root' has insufficient authority to access object 'QM'.
```

while all security is turned OFF (as far as I know) i.e.

```
ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(' ')
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
REFRESH SECURITY(*) TYPE(CONNAUTH)
```

what am I missing?

I simply want to everyone can access this QM and Queues w/o any security applied. Client is running on root account.

Comment: Why do you want to disable security?   It may be easier now in a dev or test environment but at the same time will make it that much more difficult to get it working in a production environment where you need it turned on.